# Getting image to show as background

Tags: java, javafx-11

I am trying to make an image show up as the background of my scene. Whenever I run the code, it opens the window, but the background is empty. I have tried some of the solutions from here:

[JavaFX How to set scene background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9738146/javafx-how-to-set-scene-background-image)

and from here:

[Background image in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36699991/background-image-in-javafx)

and I could not get either of them to work properly.

```
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Starbase extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Starbase Command");
        Pane pane = new Pane();
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(new Image("file:space.jpg"));
        imageView.setFitHeight(800);
        imageView.setFitWidth(800);
        pane.getChildren().add(imageView);
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't advise including the `file:` protocol in the image path.  If you package your application into a jar, with the images inside the jar, then the file protocol won't resolve it.  Instead, [retrieve the image location as a resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59029879/javafx-image-from-resources-folder).

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving my own question. The following code works as I had originally intended. Honestly not sure why it works this way and not the other, but this is what I have ended up with.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Starbase extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        // Setting the title of the window
        primaryStage.setTitle("Starbase Command");
        //Creating the pane
        StackPane stackPane = new StackPane();
        //Making the imageView for the background
        Image img = new Image("file:space.jpg");
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(img);
        imageView.setFitHeight(800);
        imageView.setFitWidth(800);
        //Adding the imageView to the stackPane
        stackPane.getChildren().add(imageView);
        Scene scene = new Scene(stackPane);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```